# How to install a previously downloaded IPSW file on iPhone directly without iTunes?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, software-update

I've downloaded the correct IPSW file for the iPhone 4 using BitTorrent. 
`iPhone3,1_7.0_11A465_Restore.ipsw`

I cannot use the Apple servers because the connection keeps dropping and the download does not resume where it left off.

The iPhone can download the file itself, but again unreliable connection prevents me from doing that.

I want to move the IPSW file to the iPhone using iFile and then tell the iPhone to update from the IPSW file on the iPhone.

Where do I place the IPSW file on the iPhone, so that it will see the file and perform the update?
And are there other files I need to update so that the iPhone will see the file.

Comment: You can browse for the IPSW to use in iTunes: http://osxdaily.com/2013/09/18/how-to-install-upgrade-ios-7-manually-with-ipsw/

Comment: Not really possible because there is more work than just uploading ipsw file. iTunes actually connects to Apple signing servers to make device-specific files. Each device has a unique id and needs a unique signature of the ipsw that iTunes makes from the downloaded file. You can google for SHSH if you are interested.

Comment: If you need to restore your phone, you'll need to restore to 7.1.2, the only currently-signed version of iOS for the iPhone 4. If you download that version to your computer, you can then restore through iTunes by option-clicking on the "Restore" button to manually select the already-downloaded IPSW. Otherwise you won't have any success.

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems here that prevents what you're trying to do:

- OTA updates don't work by downloading the IPSW and installing it. They use delta updates, only downloading a 'patch' which is applied on top of the system.

  You can download the patch yourself if you really want based on the version of iOS that you're currently on and what version you want to update to, but that's not going to help you, because…
- OTA updates don't work on jailbroken devices. You'll end up in a boot loop and have to restore properly. Many jailbreak tools disable OTA updates for this very reason.

If your Internet connection fails whilst iTunes is downloading an IPSW, it will continue from where it left off when the connection is restored.